# Warning: control reaches end of non-void function - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I keep getting 'warning: control reaches end of non-void function' with this code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

 if (section ==0)

 {
  return [comparativeList count];
 }

 if (section==1) 
 {
  return [generalList count];
 }

 if (section==2)
 {

  return [contactList count];
```

How can I get rid of this warning?

Thanks.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Add a `return 0;` at the end of your method. It's basically a failsafe, if none of the `if` conditions are met.

If you want to make sure one of the conditions is met, `return -1;` should cause the application to throw an exception and crash, which might help you track down errors.

You might also look at modifying this method and replacing the `if` statements with a `switch-case` tree. With a `switch-case` tree, you can very easily add new sections and rearrange their order in a `UITableView`. The code becomes trivially easy to read by using sensible naming conventions.

It's really easy; Fraser Speirs has a [good explanation on how to set this up](http://speirs.org/blog/2008/10/11/a-technique-for-using-uitableview-and-retaining-your-sanity.html).

Comment: +1, the OPs actual warning is likely "control reaches end of non- **void** function".

Comment: Yep, basically any method or function that says it will return something should be returning something. As there's no guarantee that any of the `if` conditions will be met, it is possible nothing will get returned.

Comment: Thanks very much it worked nicely, and your explanation was also very useful. I really appreciate your time :)

Answer (score 4):

One option:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (section ==0) {
        return [comparativeList count];
    } else if (section==1) {
        return [generalList count];
    }
    // section == 2    
    return [contactList count];
}
```