# xcode, control reaches end of non void function

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: control reaches end of non-void function - iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440337/warning-control-reaches-end-of-non-void-function-iphone)

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* print Fahrenheit-celcius table
      for fahr = 0 20, ...,300 */
int Main()
{
    int fahr,celcius;
    int upper,lower,step;

    lower = 0;    /* lower limit of temperature table */
    upper = 300;  /* upper limit of temperature table */
    step = 20;    /* step size*/ 

    fahr = lower;
    while (fahr <= upper) {
        celcius = 5 * (fahr-32) / 9;
        printf("%d\t%d\n", fahr, celcius);
        fahr = fahr + step;
    }
}
```

I get that message in Xcode I don't why !!

Answer (score 3):

If your function is declared as returning `int` (`int Main()`) than it should return an `int` (`return 0;` at the end).

An exception is the `main` function, but it is with lower case **m**. You probably meant:

```
int main() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: yes I changed the M to lower case then it worked.

Comment: @AllanRaj: now please Accept his answer.