# Error: Control reaches end of non-void function

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using following code in my `tableViewController` Class:
And the following error:

Error: Control reaches end of non-void function

```
//customize the appearance of the table view cell

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    //configure the cell

    cell.textLabel.text = [optionList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


}
```

Comment: Have you even tried googling the error message?

Comment: yes i have i get a bunch of links to this site and whenever i try using a sollution i find it never works.

Comment: @user3120442 Add this: `return cell;` at the end of your method body.

Comment: Oh my god thank you Wain!!!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: control reaches end of non-void function - iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440337/warning-control-reaches-end-of-non-void-function-iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your method with this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    //configure the cell

    cell.textLabel.text = [optionList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //This code you did not added earlier...
    return cell;

}
```

I just added `return cell;` to your code.