# When compiled it is showing warning:cannot find entry symbol Rrors;defaulting to 0000000000400590

Tags: c, c99

the while loop is not working here.there is no compilation error and the print statement is also getting executed in the beggining.the code works fine without the while loop.the code is to print the most repeating letter in a string and the number of times it is repeated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int t;
    int tempC;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while ( (tempC = getchar()) != '\n' && tempC != EOF );
    while(t--)
   {
      char c[100];
      char r='z';
      int i,j=0,count,a,k,amx;
      gets(c);
      k=strlen(c);
      for(i=0,amx=1;i<k;i++)
      {
         if(c[i]!=0)
         {
            for(j=0,count=1;j<k;j++)
            {
               if(c[i]==c[j])
               {
                  if(i!=j)
                  {
                     count++;
                     c[j]=0;
                  }
                  a=count;
                  if(a>amx||(a==amx&&(c[i]<r)))
                  {
                     amx=a;
                     r=c[i];
                  } 
               }
            }
         }

      }
      printf("%d %c\n",amx,r);
   }

}
```

Comment: Don't use `gets()` use `fgets()`.

Comment: Please elaborate *the while loop is not working*. What do you expect to see? What are you seeing that is different from what you expect to see.

Comment: never used it before.can you tell me how to implement it.i am begginer

Comment: i was expecting     abbbbb   gives 5 b     bbaa gives 2 a  but when i use while loop then i enter the no: of test cases like ex: 4 it prints 1 4 and ends

Comment: Your check for i!=j may make the count one less than you expect.

Comment: @RobertJacobs that's why i intiliased count=1 not 0

Comment: also, `if (c[i] != 0)` is redundant, as you are going from `i = 0` while `i < k` which you have initialized to be `strlen(c)`  (to get the length it searches the string for a `c[i] == 0`, so you get in `k` the actual number of charactes,  all different from `\0`)  So the `if` statement is always true.

Comment: By the way, you had better done instead of `k = strlen(c); for(i = 0; i < k; i++)` the following: `for (i = 0; c[i] != 0; i++)` because doing so you save one pass through the string (the one made by strlen just to search the end of the string).

Comment: @LuisColorado the inner for loop makes for(j=0;j<k;j++);  I making the c[j]=0 so c[i]!=0 is not always satisfied

Comment: @nani that's right, but supposing you go upstairs and you don't pass beyond `i` it's difficult to find values `== 0` beyond that place.  Either case, the implementation is difficult to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the following line is  executed,

```
scanf("%d",&t);
```

the newline character is still left in the input stream. The next call to `gets` ends up reading just the newline.

You need to add code to ignore the rest of the line after readning `t`.

```
scanf("%d",&t);

// Ignore the rest of the line from the input stream.
char c;
while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

Also, don't use `gets`.

Further reading: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

Use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: i have not used fgets before can you help me it's application.i read that it takes three arguments but i am not able to understand  the last argument.

Comment: can you please elaborate your explanation.

Comment: here is no \n in input stream.i have used it only in printf.

Comment: @nani, Let's say you typed `10` followed by Enter. At that time, the input stream has the following characters: `'1'`, `'0'`, and `'\n'`. The call to `scanf` consumes the characters `'1'` and `'0'`, assigns the value `10` to `t` but leaves the `'\n'` in the input stream.

Comment: i used scanf("%s",c); insted of gets(c); but still the same

Comment: @nani, It will be helpful to post the sample input, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: input: 3 abba  abc zzz       expected output:2 a    1 a    3 z        it prints the maximum repeating  letter and the smallest alphabet if two letters match. actual output:1   3

Comment: You may want to change the scanf to scanf("%d\n",&t) to remove the newline.

Comment: @nani, I will let you take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you mentioned, while loop works fine and just use scanf() in place of gets()(Don't use gets()) and then printf() will also be executed after loop.

Comment: i used scanf("%s",c); instead of gets(c); but no use

Comment: @nani I don't see any  problem with scanf() and it give output as you mentioned.

Comment: my new code is working but can you check if it is c99 compatible.

Comment: it is an a2 online judge question and it is showing me wrong answer.but it works fine on my compiler.@ameyCU

Answer (score 0):

You can also ask directly to your `gcc compiler`:

```
gcc test.c -o test.x -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra
```

And to be sure, try other options: `-std=gnu99`, `-std=gnu89`, `-std=c89`, and my preferred:

```
gcc test.c -o test.x -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic-errors -O0
```

Comment: I ran your preferred code it showed ISO c90 forbids mixed declarations and code int tempc;  cand.c :43:1:warning control reaches end of a non void function

Comment: Can you give me any reference so that I can figure it out?

Comment: You cannot mix declarations (like `int i;`) with commands (anything, like a `printf()` or an `if()`). You need to make all declarations in the top. And the control reaching `non-void`, is because only `void` functions are allowed to finish without `return`. A `int f()`, for example, must use a `return X;`. Remember: gcc is your second best friend, after google.

Comment: As for references, copy and past the error code inside google. It will give you some "north". Example: this google (https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=reaches%20end%20of%20non-void%20function) gives you this stackoverflow answer: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440337/warning-control-reaches-end-of-non-void-function-iphone)