# warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Tags: c, function, return, void

I got a piece of code such that:

```
int check(int d, char arr[9][9], int rep_arr[45][3]) {

    int p = findProb(d, arr, rep_arr, 0) ;

    if (isIdeal(d, arr) == 1) {

            print_array(d,arr) ;

            return 1 ;

    }

    else if(isIdeal(d,arr) == 0 && p == 0){

            printf("Fail\n") ;

            return 0 ;

    }

    else if (isIdeal(d, arr) == 0 && p != 0) {

            #do something recursively..
    }
```

where `isIdeal(d, arr)` can only be equal to `0` or `1` and `p` can be equal to `0` or another integer .
However, the compiler gives me the error that given in the title.

Later I added `return 0` at the end of that piece of code.

Now it works but didn't work in a functional manner because what the function returns is really important.

Another crucial thing is that when I add an `else` block to avoid failures indicated at another topic on that site [see more at link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440337/warning-control-reaches-end-of-non-void-function-iphone), it never entered that `else` block.However it always `return 0` whether I add an `else` block or not, by which way all the possibilities end up with a `return` line.  How ?

Comment: My real function is really long and the basic failure is given already in my problem. If I am wrong please warn me

Comment: What happens if `case1` isn't `1` or `0`.

Comment: The compiler cannot tell that the value of `case1` can only be `0` or `1`.  If the argument passed is `2`, then it would fall off the end of the function, which is why it is warning you about the problem.

Comment: If what you're telling us is true, then adding the `return 0` at the end of the function would have no effect on the behavior of the program (since it would never be reached.)

Comment: Just by looking at your code where you tested the values of `case1` to be `0` or `1` is indicative that you are expecting other values. Shouldn't you have a default return value when non of the cases were met?

Comment: @user3386109 That is the point I stuck at :( Even though I add an else block -which should cover all the other conditions- , the function still reaches the line with "return 0 ;"

Comment: My next guess is that your real function involves recursion which then continues to the end of the function when recursive call returns. That's when return 0 affects the behavior.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be asking to solve an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/244435).

Comment: @alvits yes my real funtion is recursive, does it really have an effect.Because , even if is a recursive function, it still can return only once, Am I wrong ?

Comment: You need to post a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @user3386109  I'm editing my post replacing the function with a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example, thanks

Comment: Consider this `myfunc(int,int) { if(cond) next = myfunc(2, 4); return 0 }`. The function will recurse and call `myfunc(2,4)`. When that call returns to the caller, where will it go? Of course to the return 0, because that's the next statement in the code.

Comment: What you just edited into isn't minimal, complete, or verifiable.

Comment: Let me ask you this million dollar question, not that I have a million dollar. What does your function do when the recursion returns to the caller? It has to proceed somewhere. Either returning to the caller or proceeding to the next lines of statements.

Comment: To be clear, you need to edit your code into an example that anyone could copy & paste into their IDE and recreate your problem.  Your original code was close to that.  The problem with the original form of the question was that it was an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/244435).

Comment: You left out the crucial part where it says `#do something recursively..`. When this recursive call returns, will it return to the parent within that block or will it proceed outside that block where you added `return 0;`?

Comment: I'm guessing the block where you left out the recursive call `#do something recursively..` does not have a return statement and therefore it proceeds to the next statement outside of the block, which is return 0.

Comment: @OnurTırtır: What people are telling you is that we cannot determine the problem with code you do not post. You may think you are posting the relevant parts, but if you knew where the problem was, you wouldn't need to ask here. You need to post the minimum amount of code that people can compile and that actually demonstrates your problem. Nobody can help you if you only post code that's just kinda sorta like the code you're actually having problems with.

Comment: A patient walks in and tells the doctor "this hurts" and pokes his forehead. The doc asks, your head hurts? Patient: "no". "This hurts", pokes his nose. Doc: "your nose hurts?". Patient: "no". "This hurts", pokes his tummy. Doc: "ah your stomach hurts". Patient "no!". Doc: "then what hurts?". Patient: My finger!.

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure about the possible values, then you can replace your entire function with:

```
int foo(int case1, int case2) {
    if (case1 == 1) {
        return val;
    }
    return case2 == 0 ? val2 : val3;
}
```

and silence your warning at the same time.

If you're concerned `case1` may possibly be something other than `1` or `0`, then just change to:

```
int foo(int case1, int case2) {
    assert(case1 == 0 || case1 == 1);

    if (case1 == 1) {
        return val;
    }
    return case2 == 0 ? val2 : val3;
}
```

Comment: I'd probably opt for the second implementation either way.  The only change I'd make is some doc comments above the function documenting the fact that `case1` must be `0` or `1` (or change `case1`'s type to a boolean or enum).

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does not know what the values of the `case1` and `case2` arguments will be. Your `if` conditions don't handle all possible values that those arguments might hold (ignoring that you may only be passing in 1 and 0). Thus the compiler properly warns you that you can get to the end of the function without returning anything.

If you are truly certain that this should never happen, turn this into a runtime error and put an assert at the end of the function (you may still need to return after the assert to silence the warning, I'm not sure).

```
int foo(case1, case2) {
    // your if conditions here

    assert(0);
    return 0;
}
```